# Is the better way to match two different repetitions of the same character class in a regex?

Tags: python, regex

I had been using `[0-9]{9,12}` all along to signify that the numeric string has a length of 9 or 12 characters. However I now realized that it will match input strings of length 10 or 11 as well. So I came out with the naive:

```
( [0-9]{9} | [0-9]{12} )
```

Is there a more succinct regex to represent this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could save one character by using

```
[0-9]{9}([0-9]{3})?
```

but in my opinion your way is better because it conveys your intention more clearly. Regexes are hard enough to read already.

Of course you could use `\d` instead of `[0-9]`.

(Edit: I first thought you could drop the parens around `[0-9]{3}` but you can't; the question mark will be ignored. So you only save one character, not three.)

(Edit 2: You will also need to anchor the regex with `^` and `$` (or `\b`) or `re.match()` will also match `123456789` within `1234567890`.)

Answer (score 6):

you could try

```
(\d{9}\d{3}?)
```

to match 9 and then an optional extra 3 digits

or

```
((\d{3}){3,4})
```

to match 3 or four groups of 3 digits

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
[0-9]{9}[0-9]{3}?
```

Not much different is it...